# Whats the hash algorithm of theses two hashes?

Tags: hashalgorithm

has someone an idea, which hash-algorithn was used for these two hashes:

- `$S$DjzC6BKx24dNLU4UPyiCGXo6bJ3rDYbQdf/waPOwE9X36592NiFi`
- `$S$DDLj98cyEH3azm0QvZq4E59PuczniTbfXiftWf5ED2qtcZYW5MTm`

It looks a bit salted, but i can not determine if the Salt is `$S$` or rather `$S$D`, because i know only these two. The length of these hashes without the substring `$S$` would be 52.

Answer (score 1):

- If it was salted, it would not be as easy to spot the salt.
- These are probably Base64 encoded. This means that 3 letters encode 2 bytes. Since we have 51 letters apart from the prefix `$S$D`, it is divisable by 3. That makes 34 Bytes or 136 bits.
- 136 bits are probably a hash function with 128 bits plus a CRC of 8 bits. Problem is: There are only one gazillion 128 hash funktions out there. But I'd go with md5, since it is so commonly used.